# DynamoDB Product Table Filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, nosql

I'm taking my first dive into noSQL (AWS DynamoDB) and writing a nodejs app which will maintain a product catalog. The product catalog has 2 types of item - Product and Category.

Products can appear in multiple categories. I'm really struggling to find a source of information on how best to approach this, I think using a query would be the right solution but ideally both the solution and the  data would be elegant.

At present my products look a bit like:

```
{
  "productId": 12930,
  "productCode": "DIHA",
  "name": "6 Bottle Beer Pack",
  "onSale": true,
  "newItem": false,
  "relatedItems": [1240, 1201, 4508, 55067],
  "categoryIds": [1201, 1202, 1203, 1204]
}
```

The aim is to be able to query products in a category e.g. 1203 and then filter by facets such as onSale & newItem.

I have seen an example whereby they flatten the categories like so

```
"category_1": 1201,
"category_2": 1202,
"category_3": 1203,
"category_4": 1204,
...
```

But something about that approach doesn't sit right with me (inelegant?)

I have played with using normalized tables e.g. CategoryProduct which lists the categoryIds with their related productIds.

```
{
  1201: [12930, 12931, 12932, 12933 ...],
  1202: [12930, 12678, 12679, 12680 ...],
  1203: [12930, 12500, 12501],
  1204: [12930, 12931],
  ...
}
```

But if my understanding is right then this would be quite resource heavy and lead to multiple reads just to acquire the products to filter against

Does anyone know of any tutorials or resources where filtering an entire catalog by categories or tags exists? I feel like I've trawled Google/GitHub/stackoverflow and not yet seen an example to go on.

I'll be eternally grateful if someone could share their knowledge/resources with me.

Comment: I think it appears inelegant because you have relational data that you are trying to squeeze into a NoSQL (non-relational) database. NoSQL databases aren't always the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. I partially agree... in MongoDB I believe you can query child objects but this is not so in DynamoDB which makes relational data handling a bit of a conundrum.

Comment: year 2020 and I hit a similar situation without an answer, how to relate many to many (related products) in Dynamodb